# How to do a complex Doctrine select with TYPO3 8.7?

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I try to migrate a legacy MySQL query to TYPO3 8.7 with Doctrine.

Legacy SQL statement:

```
SELECT
tt_address.*,
( 6371.41 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat ) ) * cos( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lng ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM tt_address
```

My attempt with TYPO3 8.7:

```
$statement = $queryBuilder
->select(
    'tt_address.*',
    '( 6371.41 * acos( cos( radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lat, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ') ) * cos( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat ) ) * cos( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lng ) - radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lng, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lat, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ') ) * sin( radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'
    )
->from('tt_address')
```

This leads to a completely broken SQL query:

```
SELECT `tt_address`.*,
`( 6371`.`41 * acos( cos( radians(48.0818583) ) * cos( radians(tt_address`.`tx_geosearch_lat ) ) * cos( radians(tt_address`.`tx_geosearch_lng ) - radians(11.9879884) ) + sin( radians(48.0818583) ) * sin( radians(tt_address`.`tx_geosearch_lat ) ) ) )` AS `distance`
FROM `tt_address`
```

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates

Comment: Acos, COS, radians - all not supported in select clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with the querybuilder. Nevertheless I would do it with a connection:

```
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable($tableName);
$row = $connection->executeQuery('select * from ' . $tableName . ' where uid = 1')->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thx for your hint, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addSelectLiteral()` for your query:

```
$statement = $queryBuilder
->select(
    'tt_address.*'
)
->addSelectLiteral('
    6371.41 * acos(
        cos(
            radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lat, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ')
        ) * cos( 
            radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat) 
        ) * cos( 
            radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lng) - radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lng, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ')
        ) + sin(
            radians(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($lat, \PDO::PARAM_STR) . ')
        ) * sin(
            radians(tt_address.tx_geosearch_lat)
        )
    ) AS distance
')
->from('tt_address')
```